# Convert Array to Object with grouping

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can you help me?

I have Array like this :

```js
filter = [
  ["email", "contains", "admin@admin.com"], 
  "and", 
  ["fullname", "contains", "admin"], 
  "and", 
  ["phone_number", "=", "0857214440005"]
];
```

I will converting this array to object like this :

```js
filter = {
  "contains": {
    "email": "admin@admin",
    "fullname": "admin"
  },
  "=": {
    "phone_number": ""
  }
}
```

I have tried this method but I am confused :

```
let filter = [["email", "contains" "admin@admin.com"], "and", ["fullname", "contains", "admin"], "and", ["phone_number", "=", "0857214440005"]];

// chek filter contains object or not
let boolVar = loadOptions[i].some(  
    value => { return typeof value === "object" } ); 

// if not contains, generate object and done. else next prosess
if (!boolVar) {
    let key = {};
    key[filter[0]] = filter[2]
    filter[loadOptions[i][1]] = key
} else {
     filter.forEach(item => {
       console.log(item)
     })
}
// convert from array to object
// const entries = new Map(tempFilter);
// const obj = Object.fromEntries(entries);
// console.log(obj)
```

is it possible to change like this ? thank you.

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: do you have an example and result for `'or'` values?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all arrays and joined together with an "and", you could first filter your array to only contain arrays using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), and then use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build an object. For each call of reduce callback, you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) your array to pull out the inner key (`iKey`), outer key (`oKey`) and value for your object. You can then use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) to accumulate the previously seen values into one resulting object:

```js
const arr = [["email", "contains", "admin@admin.com"], "and", ["fullname", "contains", "admin"], "and", ["phone_number", "=", "0857214440005"]];

const result = arr.filter(Array.isArray).reduce((obj, [iKey, oKey, value]) => ({
  ...obj,
  [oKey]: {
    ...(obj[oKey] || {}),
    [iKey]: value
  }
}), {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` and build an object. if the same key exist then merge values.

```js
const merge = (arr) => {
  const output = {};
  arr.filter(Array.isArray).forEach(([key, rel, value]) => {
    output[rel] ??= {};
    output[rel][key] = value;
  });
  return output;
};

filter = [
  ["email", "contains", "admin@admin.com"],
  "and",
  ["fullname", "contains", "admin"],
  "and",
  ["phone_number", "=", "0857214440005"],
];

console.log(merge(filter));
```

more concise version.

```js
const merge = (arr, output = {}) => (
  arr
    .filter(Array.isArray)
    .forEach(([key, rel, value]) => ((output[rel] ??= {})[key] = value)),
  output
);

filter = [
  ["email", "contains", "admin@admin.com"],
  "and",
  ["fullname", "contains", "admin"],
  "and",
  ["phone_number", "=", "0857214440005"],
];

console.log(merge(filter));
```